# Java Plist Location on Mac

Tags: java, plist

I am having a problem with my Plist code? When I first run the program it ask for a file location because there is no plist.

The next time I run the program and move the form and then exit the program it writes a new plist in ~library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist which is what I expect.

When I delete the above plist and restart the program I expect it to want as new file name but instead it picks the plist up from somewhere else and uses the old information.

This is the code that gets the plist

```
 // get preferences from plist
    Preferences prefsRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
    Preferences myPrefs = prefsRoot.node("WizardPreferences");

    strFileName = myPrefs.get("Path", "");
    int intPos1X = myPrefs.getInt("posScene1X", 300);
    int intPos1Y = myPrefs.getInt("posScene1Y", 300);
    intPosX = intPos1X;
    intPosY = intPos1Y;

    // check file if "" then get file name
    if (strFileName.equals("")) {
        // get file name
        filechooser();

    }
```

This is the code that writes the plist when I exit the program

```
// Exit Button
public void exit() {
    // define action for exit button
    // save information for next run
    Preferences prefsRoot = Preferences.userRoot();
    Preferences myPrefs = prefsRoot.node("WizardPreferences");
    myPrefs.put("Path", strFileName);
    myPrefs.putInt("posScene1X", intPosX);
    myPrefs.putInt("posScene1Y", intPosY);
    // exit and close program
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I am sure I have not done a good job explaining my problem as I am kinda new to Java programming.

Any help would be appreciated.

Roger

Answer (score 0):

This problem hit me recently.  It's not a problem with your code - it is the *remembering* as you said.

The Mac caches the preferences, so when you delete the plist file, the cache is still providing the information.  You can:

1. after you have deleted your plist file
2. killall -u  cfprefsd

   OR
3. reboot

Items 2. and 3. will cause the cache to be cleared and then your preferences will be reloaded as the cfprefsd restarts automatically.

I hope that helps.